# Multiplexing an 8x8 Matrix - Why Transistors?

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer

I'm trying to understand how to properly multiplex an 8x8 matrix (or any large amount of LEDs)
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RowColumnScanning

However, I'm getting a bit confused, since I've found others like this: http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/arduino-scrolling-text-marquee-to-give-a-happy-christmas

That one says to use transistors for the current switching, but the first link doesn't even use any resistors (which I find suspect), nevermind transistors.

I don't really see why the transistors are needed, can anyone explain why?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transistors are needed if the current required to drive the LEDs is higher than the microcontroller can handle. This means either a single pin current rating, or the maximum rating for all the pins together (will be given in the datasheet)

Most typical 5mm and 3mm LEDS have a maximum current rating of around 20mA and can be driven directly from a microcontroller pin (10mA is fine for most applications)
However, if your microcontrollers maximum rated current is 200mA and you want to drive 20 LEDs at 15mA, then even though the individual pins can supply the current you are out of spec for the maximum current rating.

The LEDs should always have a current limiting component (e.g. resistor) in place when driven from a voltage source, so you are right to suspect the first link. It appears that it is simply relying on the pins drive not being high enough to cause damage to the micro or the LED, which is definitely not a good idea.

Here are the the Absolute Maximum Ratings for the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf). Notice there is a per pin current rating and also a maximum total Vcc current rating:

[image: Max Specs]

Also see notes 3 and 4 on pg.314:

[image: Notes]

Also, you can get high power LEDs with current ratings of >500mA, so a transistor is obviously the only option in this case.

Comment: I'm using one of these: http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/BL-M07C881.PDF
The UltraBright Red variety. It seems that max current per LED is 30mA. 

It would seem that there's no way without the transistors though since you're driving one column at a time so it would be 8x30mA. But obviously people do it. I have a watch with an 8x8 matrix that uses no transistors, so it's possible... Am I figuring the current calculations wrong?

Comment: No, you can run the chip beyond the recommended specs, it's just that Atmel do not guarantee what will happen if you do. If it's only slightly over, and your conditions (e,g, ambient temperature, etc) are not likely to stress the chip, then you will probably get away with it. It's not the way to design a professional product though, always work within the recommended specs.

Comment: Also, remember that with a matrix you don't have to have all the LEDs on at once if you are scanning through at e.g. 100Hz, so the current can be kept within specs. For example, if each LED in your watch uses 10mA, then if one column is scanned at a time the maximum possible average draw is 80mA.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't that mean that the current draw on the pin that controls that column would be 80mA which is > 40mA? And wouldn't this be the case regardless of the control pin being the current source or sink?

Comment: Yes sorry, you would have to split the scan up more if the columns are driven from pins also (I was thinking of transistors on each column for some reason) If both columns and  rows are driven from the pins, then a maximum of 4 LEDs per column can be lit at any time. Ideally you would only light 2, as the 40mA is the absolute maximum rating, which is not recommended.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Now I just wonder how anyone ever drives these things directly from the I/O pins :P

Comment: They quickly scan one or two LEDs at a time (if the scan speed is  high enough, the eye sees all the LEDs on at once - see POV), or diagonally, or ignore specs and hope for the best ;-) Basically though, unless you are using a small matrix driving at very low currents, then use transistors - for the minimal extra cost and effort, you have a far larger drive capability and less to worry about (e.g. you can light all LEDs at once of you wish) For the display you link to, I would definitely use transistors (plus  current limiting resistors)

Comment: In the tutorial http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RowColumnScanning I feel like when we set row LOW (anode) and all columns HIGH (cathode) we leave the row leds with reversed polarity. Will it damage the leds?

Comment: Reversed polarity is okay as long as it does not exceed the datasheet value, so check this and as long as you are safely within it you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually false, transistors are used as a switch. This lets you switch the cathode pins using a positive signal from an arduino such that each LED in the matrix can be individually controlled, allowing for the possibility of multiplexing. Simple.

Answer (score -1):

You should read this post http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2015/12/scrolling-text-led-matrix-8x8-using-arduino-proteus-isis.html .... They have shown in detail how to interface arduino with 8x8 led matrix. They have used MAX7219 in order to do so. The code is also given there along with Proteus simulation.